# Getting "confused by unstable object source data" on git in visual studio code when I try to commit. Other similar questions didn't offer a quick fix

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CIzJ.png) Also, a bunch of what are apparently 'objects' (long strings of letters and numbers) were present upon opening Git in VS. I say this because maybe the two are connected somehow... this is my first time using visual studio code. I used the GitHub extension by KnisterPeter.

Comment: Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio Team Explorer? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/work-team-explorer). Do you have a screen shot illustrating the issue?

Comment: visual studio code

Comment: OK. Do you have a screenshot? Or the URL to a screenshot?

Comment: i put it in the thingy

Comment: It's all the long alphanumeric stuff on the left

Comment: OK, can you try and delete the /home/maya/.git/index.lock file? Also are you sure you want a git repo in your /home/maya?

Comment: And what is the full path of one of those files with a long alphanumeric sequence in their name?